# Resolve files in maven dependency relatively to it's location

Tags: java, maven, resources

I have maven project A and it use some files located under `src/main/resources`. When I import project A to project B and execute functionality that use this files I get exception that files not found, but they are located in project A maven's build.

How it's possible to force reading files from regardless to place where this project used?

Comment: Quite vague. If your files are in A's artifact, you might use `getResource()` to fetch them.

Comment: The question is how you are trying to read the files?